# Distinct + Order By in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, sql-order-by, distinct

Related to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592220/collection-sorting-in-basis-of-two-parameters-simultaneously)

I have worked with that answer, but now I require to do with a bit modification using hibernate.

I need to now add a string to `TestData` class say `String name`
Then I want to fetch Collection of `TestData` from db using hibernate with the distinct name and sorting as I did in the `CollectionSort class`.

Can anyone help me how to do this using hibernate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse that comparator in Hibernate, using [`@Sort`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/Sort.html) annotation

- [Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted)

Comment: Thanks, It will help for comparator, But I also want to fetch distinct objects based on `name` which is the prime requirement later I can do with what is being done, any inputs for that?